# Subversive: Change SVN commit message retroactively?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Actually I need to modify SVN commit message. A lot of related staff exists how to do it (e.g. [Change SVN commit message retroactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184317/change-svn-commit-message-retroactively)).

My question is, could I do it from Eclipse's subversive plugin?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not easy to find, but possible. This recipe is working for Eclipse Indigo (`3.6`) and Subversive `0.7.9I20110321-1700`. Do the following steps:

1. Open for an item where you want to change a log message the history: `Team > Show History`. This opens a new view named `History`.
2. In that view, you see the log messages of the selected item. Select one of the messages and choose from the context menu `Show revision properties`.
3. Select `svn:log` and then from the context menu `Edit...`. This opens a new dialog where you can change the log message (if allowed on the server).

The best answer I found at Stackoverflow to the base question was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304390/41540) that states clearly that it is not the default behavior of a Subversion server to allow that, so normally, it won't be possible without the help of an administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution is broken for Eclipse 3.7 + SVN Kit 1.7 (with SVN Kit 1.6 it works).

Constantly get an exception:
SVN: 'Set revision property' operation finished with error: svn: E195011: Revision property 'svn:log' not allowed in this context
svn: E195011: Revision property 'svn:log' not allowed in this context

Comment: Works fine with Eclipse 4.2.2

Comment: There is an easier solution for Subclipse users: Team -> Show History -> right-click on a revision -> Set Commit Properties. It works with Eclipse 4.3.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer. You have to have changed the configuration of your repository, as referenced in the other answer. So it works for you, because your administrator has done the necessary changes.

Answer (score 6):

As gouessej commented, for quick reference, the process for me was:

1. `Team > Show History`
2. Right click on an element in the list and select `Set Commit Properties`

Comment: This is not allowed and I got message requesting the admin to enable this. How I can add a commit message with no changes?